# Create a folder using user information for the folder name

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my project I already have working controller, route and frontend code that save my user's personal information.
What I'd like to do is to also create a folder with my user information in the user's laptop.
This is my controller code

controllers/data.js

```
exports.saveInformation = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const newData = new Information({
    name: req.body.name,
    last_name: req.body.last_name,

    });
    const savedData = await newData.save();
    if (!savedData) {
      res.status(500).json({ isError: true });
    }
    createFolder ;
    res.status(200).json({ isError: false });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(300).json({ isError: true });
  }
};


createFolder = () => {
  var dir = `./tmp/${name}-${last_name}`;
  if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(dir);
  }
}
```

The code is not giving me back any error, but it doesn't create the new folder.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It doesn't appear that you actually calling the function createFolder. try to replace line 12 (`createFolder ;`) with `createFolder();` this should then error for you. — Additionally you will need to pass the data in `createFolder(newData);` to be used. And then update your function to use `= (newData) => {` and `./tmp/${newData.name}-${newData.last_name}`

Comment: An `fs.mkdir` call on the node.js **server** will never "*create a folder […] in the user's laptop*"

Comment: have you tried using absolute path to the mkdirsync?